# How can I set this up so that if I click on a button, the value changes in a number picker and vice versa?

Tags: java, android

I want to be able to check one one of the eleven buttons I currently have set up and have the value of the button update inside a custom number picker I made and vice versa. So that if I pick a number in the number picker, I want the button to be depressed/clicked on for that same value.

I'm looking for the best/most reasonable approach. I was thinking maybe if I put everything inside an if-else statement but I'm not sure how that would work.

Here's my code so far:

```
 int buttonValue = 0;

   //onClickListener method that returns an interface
    private View.OnClickListener createClickListener(final int value) {
        return new View.OnClickListener()  {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                buttonValue = value;

                ToggleButton clickedButton = (ToggleButton) view;
                RadioGroup radioGroup= (RadioGroup) clickedButton.getParent();

                for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                    View nextChild = radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                    if (!(nextChild instanceof ToggleButton)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (nextChild.getId() != clickedButton.getId() || !clickedButton.isChecked()) {
                        ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton) nextChild;
                        tb2.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            }

        };
    }



   @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup parent, final int position) {

                final int delPosition = position;
                //Get the inflater
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                //inflate the root layout
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.collection, null);

                //scores toggle buttons
                zero = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_zero);
                one = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_one);
                two = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_two);
                three = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_three);
                four = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_four);
                five = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_five);
                six = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_six);
                seven = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_seven);
                eight = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_eight);
                nine = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_nine);
                ten = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_ten);

                zero.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(0));
                one.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(1));
                two.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(2));
                three.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(3));
                four.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(4));
                five.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(5));
                six.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(6));
                seven.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(7));
                eight.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(8));
                nine.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(9));
                ten.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(10));

                final ImageView plus_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.plus_sign);
                final ImageView minus_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.minus_sign);

                final int[] counter = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
                final TextView num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.num);
                num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));

                  plus_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View view, final int value) {

                            if (plus_button.isPressed()) {

                                if ((counter[0] <= 9) && (counter[0] >= 0)) {

                                    counter[0]++;
                                    num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));
                                    buttonValue = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    });

                    minus_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            if (minus_button.isPressed()) {

                                if ((counter[0] <= 10) && (counter[0] > 0)) {
                                    counter[0]--;
                                    num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));
                                    buttonValue = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                parent.addView(view, 0);
                return view;
            }
```

Here's part of the xml file:

```
//Custom number picker


        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/minus_sign"
                android:src="@drawable/minus"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/num"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                />

        <ImageView

                android:id="@+id/plus_sign"
                android:src="@drawable/plus"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="2"
                />


//The buttons are toggle buttons inside a radiogroup 

<RadioGroup>

        <ToggleButton

                    android:id="@+id/number_zero"
                    android:layout_width="25sp"
                    android:layout_height="35sp"
                    android:textOn="@string/number_zero"
                    android:textOff="@string/number_zero"
                    android:background="@drawable/number_color"
                    />

        <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/number_one"
                    android:layout_width="25sp"
                    android:layout_height="35sp"
                    android:textOn="@string/number_one"
                    android:textOff="@string/number_one"
                    android:background="@drawable/number_color"
                />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: can you add the xml file too

Comment: Is there something particular you want to see? I can add a snippet.

Comment: A little confused about what your custom number picker is. Are these 11 buttons part of the custom number picker or is the custom number picker a separate view?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what to call it (Maybe number picker is wrong) but basically I have a minus sign and a plus sign and when I click on minus, I am decreasing the value in the textview and if I click on plus,  I am increasing the value in the textview. I updated my post so you can see what I mean

Comment: 11 buttons are not part of the custom number picker, they in the same view but separate from the picker. Just think of them as separate widgets (they are not widgets but I think of widgets are parts).

Comment: OK so you just want to change the value between 0 and 10?

Comment: I am already changing the value but I am wondering if I change the value in one "widget" how can i change the value in the other simultaneously? How can I change the values in both "widgets" at the same time? That is, they have to be in sync and change to the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your collection of toggle buttons, use `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` or any other type that can be cast to `ViewGroup`. Then after you inflated the view, cast it to `ViewGroup`, then use `view.getChildAt(i)` to get the corresponding `ToggleButton` . Better than finding all buttons by id, wouldn't it?

This is similar to what you've done to the radio buttons.

--

```
  int buttonValue = 0;

   //onClickListener method that returns an interface
   private View.OnClickListener createClickListener(final int value) {
    return new View.OnClickListener()  {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            buttonValue = value;

            ToggleButton clickedButton = (ToggleButton) view;
            RadioGroup radioGroup= (RadioGroup) clickedButton.getParent();

            // **Change your TextView here
            ...

            // **Keep these since you still want to update all buttons
            for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                View nextChild = radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                if (!(nextChild instanceof ToggleButton)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (nextChild.getId() != clickedButton.getId() || !clickedButton.isChecked()) {
                    ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton) nextChild;
                    tb2.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }

    };
}



   @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup parent, final int position) {

            final int delPosition = position;
            //Get the inflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)     parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //inflate the root layout
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.collection, null);

            // **Initialize your components earlier
            final int[] counter = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
            final TextView num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.num);
            num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));

            // **Give your RadioGroup an id so that you can find it here
            ViewGroup group = view.findViewById(...);
            // **Loop through this group then for each child, set your listener
           for (...){
                      child=group.getChildAt(i);
                      child.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(i));
            }

            final ImageView plus_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.plus_sign);
            final ImageView minus_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.minus_sign);


              plus_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view, final int value) {

                        if (plus_button.isPressed()) {

                            if ((counter[0] <= 9) && (counter[0] >= 0)) {

                                counter[0]++;
                                num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));
                                buttonValue = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
                                // **Use the loop here again to update all buttons
                                for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                                         View nextChild = group.getChildAt(i);
                                         ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton) nextChild;
                                         if (i==buttonValue) {
                                         tb2.setChecked(true);
                                      } else {tb2.setChecked(false);}
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });

                minus_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (minus_button.isPressed()) {

                            if ((counter[0] <= 10) && (counter[0] > 0)) {
                                counter[0]--;
                                num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));
                                buttonValue = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
                                // **Use the loop here again to update all buttons
                                for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                                         View nextChild = group.getChildAt(i);
                                         ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton) nextChild;
                                         if (i==buttonValue) {
                                         tb2.setChecked(true);
                                      } else {tb2.setChecked(false);}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            parent.addView(view, 0);
            return view;
        }
```

--

You run your loop for setting click listeners on this `RadioGroup` in your xml *only*. Do not run your loop on the entire xml

```
<RadioGroup>

    <ToggleButton

                android:id="@+id/number_zero"
                android:layout_width="25sp"
                android:layout_height="35sp"
                android:textOn="@string/number_zero"
                android:textOff="@string/number_zero"
                android:background="@drawable/number_color"
                />

    <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/number_one"
                android:layout_width="25sp"
                android:layout_height="35sp"
                android:textOn="@string/number_one"
                android:textOff="@string/number_one"
                android:background="@drawable/number_color"
            />
  </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: So, I would do the same thing almost for the minus button as well? Thanks. EDIT: by looping through the radiogroup, I would do the same thing as I did in the CreateOnClickListener for the toggle buttons.

Comment: @KalaJ yes, you can do it either before or after `num.setText()`.

Comment: @KalaJ I think you can move your current loop in `createOnClickListener` to the place I suggested.

Comment: For the loop, it says, "android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.ToggleButton" The ImageView is the plus and minus buttons, they are images.

Comment: Also, I need the loop inside my CreateClickListener because I want to be able to have the toggle buttons act like radio buttons (only one allowed to be selected). If I remove the loop, the multiple toggle buttons can be selected at one time. Sorry for the trouble but thanks for your help! :D

Comment: @KalaJ check the edit. All comments starting with `**` is my change to your code. Sorry if my previous answers caused confusion.

Comment: Oh wait no... nvm. I didn't see the update properly. one sec.

Comment: @KalaJ yeah my previous answer caused confusion. You keep your view as in `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.collection, null);`, and you give your original `RadioGroup` in your original xml file an id, and then you find that id through `ViewGroup group = view.findViewById(...);`, and then you loop and set listener on that `ViewGroup`.

Comment: When you say, "// **Use the loop here again to update all buttons", which loop are you referring to?

Comment: @KalaJ the one in your `createOnClickListener`. But this time you use `group` instead of `radioGroup` that you declared in that function.

Comment: Ok but clickedButton is  "ToggleButton clickedButton = (ToggleButton) view;" in my loop and android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.ToggleButton

Comment: @KalaJ see edit. My earlier answers probably got your head burnt. Give yourself some rest and come back to it later and see if things become clearer. It's straightforward. If you click on any toggle button, update all buttons and update your text. If you click on plus/minus sign, update all buttons and update your text.

Comment: thanks for your help. It's still buggy, I think it might be my for loop,   "for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                        View child = group.getChildAt(i);
                        child.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(i));
                    }" where I am setting the click listener.

Comment: what is supposed to be this? // **Loop through this group then for each child, set your listener
           for (...){
                      child=group.getChildAt(i);
                      child.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(i));
            }. What goes inside for statement?

Comment: @KalaJ `for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); ++i)`

Comment: hm strange. Okay I give up. I have this and it's not working properly:  for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                        View child = group.getChildAt(i);
                        child.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(i));
                    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64436/discussion-between-stonebird-and-kala-j).

Comment: StoneBird, I found a bug. If I change a value on my first view and I click on plus or minus on my second view, it should not start from the value I changed on my first view. What should I do?

Comment: @KalaJ in this case you just hold an array of counter values where each item in the array corresponds to the counter in a single page in your page viewer. Remember what you did for holding multiple TextView? This is the same idea.

Comment: Okay but I guess I am wondering how do I know that each element in the array coresponds to the counter in a single page? How do I set something up like that in a viewpager? I am not manually creating different views for this. I created a new question btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865743/how-can-i-stop-elements-from-affecting-other-elements-inside-a-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

You could store all of your togglebuttons inside of an array.

Keep a global int for the currently selected toggle button's index value. (This should always be between 0 and 10)

Write a refreshUI function. It should remove the high light from the toggle buttons, then it should go to the toggle button located at that global index value inside the array and high light it. It should also write that toggle buttons value in the text view.

When a toggle button is pressed, update the global index value to where in the array that toggle button is located and then refreshUI.

When a plus/minus is pressed, make sure the global index value is within 0-10 range, change it (by +1 or -1) and refreshUI.

```
// Class fields.
private int lastButtonIndex = 0;
// In the onCreate method put all the toggle buttons in this array.
private ToggleButton[] toggleButtons=new ToggleButton[11]; 

private void refreshUI(){ 
   for(ToggleButton button : toggleButtons){
     //set each button background to white.
   }
   // set the background color of the toggleButtons[lastButtonIndex] to red.
   // set the textview text to the value of toggleButtons[lastButtonIndex].
}
```

Comment: What do toy mean by refresh ui function?

Comment: Its a function that each toggle button and the plus/minus button will call in the end of their onclicklistener.

Comment: In that function it should determine which button should be red and what value the textview should be.

Comment: Why do I need a lastButtonIndex for?

Comment: To know which toggle button is chosen. When a toggle button is chosen change the lastButtonIndex value to the toggle buttons index number in the toggleButtons array. When the plus and minus signs are hit you can easily  change it by just adding/subtracting one instead of using the counter to find the button.