# How can I stop elements from affecting other elements inside a viewpager?

Tags: java, android

I am just trying to connect a group of toggle buttons (under a radiogroup hierarchy) and setting them based on a counter that increments or decrements depending on what button you pick.

I am currently placing this inside a viewpager that does not use fragments. It's uses just regular views with some dynamic elements. I use a pageradapter to go through the views.

I think the problem I am having has to do with using a viewpager and having the toggle button group ids and the counter ids being the same on every view. So, I think the elements on each view are effecting each other because of it?

The next view is effected by the previous view's value that is set by the counter. So if I click on 3 in the previous view and then I click on the plus sign (where starting value is zero), it jumps to 4 because on the previous view I selected 3.

So, here's what I have so far in snippets and it mostly works:

**Inner class inside of the Pager Activity**

```
    private View.OnClickListener createClickListener(final int value, final int position) {
        return new View.OnClickListener()  {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                buttonValue = value;
                counter = buttonValue;

                ToggleButton clickedButton = (ToggleButton) view;
                RadioGroup radioGroup= (RadioGroup) clickedButton.getParent();

                num.get(position).setText(Integer.toString(buttonValue));
                map.put(position, buttonValue);

               for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                    View nextChild = radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                    if (!(nextChild instanceof ToggleButton)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (nextChild.getId() != clickedButton.getId() || !clickedButton.isChecked()) {
                        ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton) nextChild;
                        tb2.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            }

        };
    }

    **Inside InstantiateItem() of viewPager:** 

    num.add(position, (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.num));
    num.get(position).setText(Integer.toString(counter));

    final ImageView plus_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.plus_sign);
                    final ImageView minus_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.minus_sign);

                    final ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.toggleGroup);

                    for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                        View child = group.getChildAt(i);
                        child.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(i, position));
                    }

       plus_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            if (plus_button.isPressed()) {

                                if ((counter <= 9) && (counter >= 0)) {

                                    counter++;
                                    num.get(position).setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                                    buttonValue = Integer.parseInt(num.get(position).getText().toString());
                                    for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                                        View nextChild = group.getChildAt(i);
                                        ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton) nextChild;
                                        if (i == buttonValue) {
                                            tb2.setChecked(true);
                                        } else {
                                            tb2.setChecked(false);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    System.out.println(num.get(position).getText().toString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    minus_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            if (minus_button.isPressed()) {

                                if ((counter <= 10) && (counter > 0)) {
                                    counter--;
                                    num.get(position).setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                                    buttonValue = Integer.parseInt(num.get(position).getText().toString());
                                    for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                                        View nextChild = group.getChildAt(i);
                                        ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton) nextChild;
                                        if (i == buttonValue) {
                                            tb2.setChecked(true);
                                        } else {
                                            tb2.setChecked(false);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    System.out.println(num.get(position).getText().toString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity where you created an array of `TextView`s, you basically do the similar thing. Create an array of integers, say you declare `int [] counter = new {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`. And then, in your current code, for all operations on `counter`, you just perform the same operation on `counter[position]` instead.

Comment: What could be wrong with the save button here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836706/how-can-i-show-a-button-when-all-views-are-viewed-in-viewpager

Comment: @KalaJ you don't expect me to walk you through your app, do ya? :P